# Fork project gitlab

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to get a copy of project from specific subgroup and create new project with this copy in another subgroup under the same group.
note:- I suppose to know the path for the target project to be created from variables I will get from database so I cannot use subgroup id directly.

```
var project = gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getGroup("parent-group/subgroup1/sub2/sub3/lastSubgroup").getProjects().get(0);
```

Here I got the project correctly.
my issue with copying it in another subgroup path

```
gitLabApi.getProjectApi().createProject("testname",gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getGroup("parent-group/targetsubgroup1/targetsub2/../targetlastSubgroup").getPath()).setForkedFromProject(project);
```

It runs the command but I cannot see any forked project created.
when I add the path as string path I get validation error in path.

Itried also

```
Project newProject = gitLabApi.getProjectApi().forkProject(project.getId(),gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getGroup("parent-group/targetsubgroup1/targetsub2/../targetlastSubgroup").getProjects().get(0).getNamespace().getName(),gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getGroup("parent-group/targetsubgroup1/targetsub2/../targetlastSubgroup","projnameSara");
```

I got 404 not found namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution for my issue.

- first you have to make sure that the user you use in Gitlab has a maintainer permission.
- then I got the project as I want from group or from project path with var called "project".
- then used gitLabApi.getProjectApi().forkProject(project.getId(),gitLabApi.getGroupApi().getGroup("parentGroup/subgroup1/subgroup2/lastSubgroup").getId().toString(),"testFromPortal","testFromPortal");
- notice that "testFromPortal" is refering to path and name for forked project.